# Why does code run correctly in debugging?

Tags: vba, debugging

I am trying to export/ read some data. In order to do it, I check the data for two criteria: data row should be marked with "x" in Overview Sheet and the data should be exported in a given order (for this purpose I use integer h). Shorly, if the data row has "x" in Column G and Column H of the same row contains the smallest integer, then the data should be exported. The process must be repeated for all integers available.

I use the following code

```
Sub ShowData()
Dim destRng As Range
Dim h As Integer
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("Einlesen.xlsm")
Set Rng = wb.Worksheets("Overview").Range("G7:G1000")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
wb.Worksheets("Output").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Worksheets("Output").Copy After:=Worksheets("Overview")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets("Overview").Index + 1)
wsNew.Name = "Ergebnis"
Set ARng = Worksheets("Ergebnis").Range("B1:C98")
For h = 1 To 20
For Each rngCell In Rng
If rngCell.Value = "x" And Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column + 1) = h Then
'Do the job
End If  
Next rngCell
Next h  
Worksheets("Ergebnis").Columns("B:C").Hidden = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Worksheets("Ergebnis").Visible = True
End Sub
```

When I debug at point "Next h", then the code performs correctly, otherwise it takes the first integer and completes the performance.
How can I adjust my code, that it runs correctly even in run mode?

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have a mixture of fully qualified,  partially qualified and unqualified references to ranges, worksheets and workbooks.   Fix all those,  then see if the problem persists

Comment: Also, please use *indenting* when posting code.  For your own sanity too...